# SQL - Select distinct record in one column based on criteria in another

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I understand there are similar questions but I haven't found one that discusses this yet...

Example Sales table. Need to return Name of individual who did not sell product type 'A' on 21-Feb-16

```
Name        Date            Product Type
John        21-Feb-16       A
John        21-Feb-16       B
Joe         21-Feb-16       D
Joe         21-Feb-16       B
Jane        21-Feb-16       A
Jane        21-Feb-16       D
```

Desired return:

```
Name        
Joe
```

Need something more than just...

```
select 
distinct Name
from Sales
where Name = 'Joe'
```

Comment: Well, obviously you need something more than that !?!?! But first figure out which RDBMS you're using.

Comment: where are the `date` & `Product Type` conditions?

Comment: mysql and sql server are not the same database.  Please pick one.

Answer (score 0):

just read about Not in

```
select *
from Sales
where Name not in 
(select name
from Sales
where Date='21-Feb-16'
and product_type='A')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a table like `SalesPerson`; using `not exists()`:

```
select Name
from SalesPerson sp
where not exists (
  select 1
  from Sales s
  where s.SalesPersonId = sp.SalesPersonId
    and s.ProductType = 'A'
    and s.date = '20160221' 
  )
```

otherwise:

```
select distinct Name
from Sales s
where not exists (
  select 1
  from Sales i
  where s.Name = i.Name
    and i.ProductType = 'A'
    and i.date = '20160221'
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`EXCEPT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql) operator for this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name
FROM Sales
EXCEPT
SELECT Name
FROM Sales
WHERE ProductType = 'A' AND Date = '21-Feb-16'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `NOT in` and a subselect like the following. In practical way you retrieve all the sellers excluding the sellers who sold at least one product of type A

```
select distinct 
    Name
from 
    Sales
where 
    Name not in (select distinct Name
                 from Sales
                 where Product_type = 'A' and date '21-feb-2016')
```

Answer (score -2):

How about using:

```
select 
Name
from Sales
where Name = 'Joe'
group by Name
```